# Recursive GET login using Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

C# developer learning Rails, so forgive me anything that seems basic.  I am using Devise for login authentication.

First, I have a few routes setup in my routes.rb as:

```
devise_for :user, skip: [:sessions, :passwords], controllers: { sessions: "portal/sessions" }

devise_scope :user do
  root to: "portal/sessions#new"

  get "login", to: "portal/sessions#new", as :new_portal_session
end
```

My user.rb model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    devise :database_authenticatable, :recoverable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

When I hit localhost:3000 for the first time, everything works great.  Able to see the login page, enter credentials, etc.  After I login, it redirects me to my portal/portal#dashboard as expected.

However, once I am logged in and I try to hit the localhost:3000 (root or login page) again, it falls into a recursive loop with the following output in terminal (via "rails s"):

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at <DATE>
...removed
...removed
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 30ms (ActiveRecord: 27.9ms)
```

I have to CTRL-C the server to get it to stop.  If I completely close all tabs on the browser and when reopen localhost:3000 from a fresh browser start it shows the login screen again as normal.

Anyone lead me into the right direction on why this is happening or how to fix it?

Thanks, as always!

**EDITED:**
Added SessionsController as requested.

Here is the code from the SessionsController.

```
class Portal::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  respond_to :json, only: [:create]
  layout "portal/public"

  def new
    super
  end

  def create
    super
  end
end
```

Comment: You have a custom sessions controller. The problem might be there. Can you put the code from it?

Comment: I've added it to the above question.

Comment: Looks like your sending the logged in user to a page that requires the user to be logged out.  Do you have a before_action anywhere that calls require_no_authentication?

Comment: root to: "portal/sessions#new"  and get "login", to: "portal/sessions#new", as :new_portal_session

Do the same thing. Have you tried removing either line and trying again? If this does not work, I'll try to recreate the problem.

Comment: @Swards No, I am not doing that anywhere in my code.

Comment: @Histro Georgiev Removing the root route causes the standard "Welcome Aboard" page to appear.  Removing the root and then going directly to /login causes it to redirect to root (which is the Welcome aboard screen).

Comment: yeah - the sessions/new page will have a non-logged in requirement.  Be sure your root page is something other than login.

Comment: @Histro Georgiev Removing the login route (but leaving the root route) causes the same behavior listed above.

Comment: @Swards okay, so I am getting it.  The problem is that the user is LOGGED in, but has no path available to redirect to, so Devise automatically redirects them to root (which is the login screen) and thus the loop?  Am I on the right track?

Comment: Yes that's right.  The root page is the default for this, you can override that, I suspect, but I think you probably want a root page that can handle logged in or not.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Sewards suggestion, I changed the root route to point to "portal/dashboard@index" (the landing page) and gave it a name of user_root_path.

This solved the issue above.

Based on the Devise documentation:

> After signing in a user, confirming the account or updating the
>   password, Devise will look for a scoped root path to redirect to. For
>   instance, when using a :user resource, the user_root_path will be used
>   if it exists; otherwise, the default root_path will be used.